# how to keep all elements searched in an array list and search for a specific element in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to keep all elements searched in an array list and search for a specific element in selenium web driver.

Example:

I searched for an item in amazon.com i would get a list of items how to save it in list and iterate keeping in mind that the search is dynamic.

Comment: use List to store and Iterate through it...e.g. 
`List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.className("knx-oasFrame0")); for (WebElement iframe : iframes) {
System.out.println(iframe.getAttribute("id"));
}`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: question is clear @DebanjanB i want all element which i searched from amazon in a list and want to iterate via list.In a simple English language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Abhishek ::

```
    List<WebElement> List = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*********"));

    // System.out.println(List.size()); // Print total count

    for (int i = 0; i<List.size(); i++) 
    {    
        System.out.println(List.get(i).getText());          
    }
```